# the `wasm32-wasi` target may not be installed while it is installed

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-wasm, rustup

why `cargo build --target wasm32-wasi` throws and error about not having `wasm32-wasi` while it is installed.
steps to reproduce

1. cargo new train
2. rustup target add wasm32-wasi
3. cargo build --target wasm32-wasi

the output to the console is next

```
➜  train git:(master) ✗ cargo build --target wasm32-wasi
   Compiling train v0.1.0 (/user/playground/rustLang/train)
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
  |
  = note: the `wasm32-wasi` target may not be installed
  = help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add wasm32-wasi`

error: cannot find macro `println` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     println!("hello");
  |     ^^^^^^^

error: requires `sized` lang_item

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `train` due to 3 previous errors
➜  train git:(master) ✗ rustup target add wasm32-wasi
info: component 'rust-std' for target 'wasm32-wasi' is up to date
➜  train git:(master) ✗
```

Comment: Maybe try `cargo clean` and rebuild, it just works here..

Comment: Mandatory question: Is `cargo` actually the `cargo` you installed with `rustup`, or do you have a second `cargo` installed somewhere else? What does the command `which cargo` print?

Comment: @Finomnis so `which cargo` results in `/opt/homebrew/bin/cargo`

Comment: That's probably the problem, you have it installed through both homebrew and rustup simultaneously. Uninstall the homebrew version and the problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I'm on MacOS:

```
❮ cargo wasi build --release                                                                                                         
error: failed to find the `wasm32-wasi` target installed, and rustup is also not detected, you'll need to be sure to install the `wasm32-wasi` target before using this command
```

It turns out that I was using a homebrew installation of rust:

```
❯ which cargo                                                                                                                          
/opt/homebrew/bin/cargo
```

The solution was to uninstall the homebrew version of rust and then install the version from the instructions on rust-lang.org (actual code may vary. Just got to https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install and follow the instructions)

```
❯ brew uninstall rust                                                                                                                  
Uninstalling /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rust/1.67.1... (36,648 files, 891.6MB)

❯ curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that you didn't register the terminal before run the command:
Please confirm that you have installed emsdk from: [emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html)

After downloaded open the powershell terminal and go to emsdk folder and execute the following commands:

**./emsdk install latest**

**./emsdk activate latest**

In the emsdk and wat2wasm documentation it is necessary to register the terminal and load the emsdk references before executing any other command.
In the documentation, you are instructed to do this procedure every time for each new instance or new terminal window opened.

Reinstall rust from: [rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install)

check if environment variables are ok and try again

Answer (score -2):

You already had the answer in the line:

help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add wasm32-wasi`

in the command prompt just type: > rustup target install wasm32-wasi

Comment: this did nothing, i showed i tried to do that, the whole terminal window is present in question